# After PC restarted the vagrant machine fails to starts. It shows port collision

Tags: vagrant

**UPDATE:** [After host PC reboot vagrant up shows port collision on any port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088209/after-host-pc-reboot-vagrant-up-shows-port-collision-on-any-port)

My vagrant machine fails to start.
Usually it was working normally, but today after I restarted my PC the vagrant machine no more starts.
I did not change the Vagrantfile.
It says about ports collision.
If I remove the 6379 setting for redis, then it says for port 1080 and so on.
Like all ports have the collision.
If I try to run the macine via VMware - then it starts OK, but I cannont connect to it via ssh, because it doesn't have the settings that are defined in Vagrantfile...

Here is the log:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: There was a problem while downloading the metadata for your box
==> default: to check for updates. This is not an error, since it is usually due
==> default: to temporary network problems. This is just a warning. The problem
==> default: encountered was:
==> default:
==> default: The requested URL returned error: 404
==> default:
==> default: If you want to check for box updates, verify your network connectio                                                                                                                                                                                               n
==> default: is valid and try again.
==> default: Fixed port collision for 6379 => 6379. Now on port 2250.
Vagrant found a port collision for the specified port and virtual machine.
While this port was marked to be auto-corrected, the ports in the
auto-correction range are all also used.

VM: default
Forwarded port: 1080 => 1080
```

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  forward_port = ->(guest, host = guest) do
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
      guest: guest,
      host: host,
      auto_correct: true
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "sites/", "/var/www"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true


  forward_port[6379]      # redis
  forward_port[1080]      # mailcatcher
  forward_port[3306]      # mysql
  forward_port[80, 8080]  # nginx/apache

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
  end

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.10"

  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
end
```

Comment: Have you actually checked if this ports are occupied or not?

Comment: I did not check, because I know that they are unusued. They ever was unused and I did not install any new software on the PC. I do not have any local web server/redis/ mysql server etc... installed on the host pc. So the ports are unused 100%

Comment: If I leave only one forward_port, then it forwards to 2250 and machine starts. also the machine starts if I remove all forward_port settings. If I change to any port 13245, 30303 etc... all ports are shown as used that cannot actually be.... If I even write 2250 port, then It shows that is busy and redirects to 2249 port lol...